# How do I set an image as background without blurring?

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio. I am trying to set a screenshot from my device, as a background image for my activity -

```
android:background="@drawable/active"
```

I have my image inside the directory- `res> drawable-ldpi> active.jpeg` , Which Is the lowest density folder available I am aware of. The problem is, The background looks PERFECTLY crisp and sharp in the screenshot, but when I set it as my activity's background, it blurs.

How do I fix this? I have tried moving the image to the highest density folder `drawable-XXXhdpi`, but it becomes worse. I have even tried the drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

All depends on your phone density. You should make few version of your image for each pixel density (but remember that even mdpi is growing older). If you properly resize image for each density your phone should take needed size of background.